# Issue with manual implementation of Enhanced conversions for Google Ads via GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm having issues with implementation of Enhanced conversions in Google Ads. Would be really appreciative if someone could give me some pointers to the right direction or any suggestion regarding what to try.

The error message I'm receiving is the one below:

"User address data field is incorrectly formatted
Make sure user address is correctly formatted and hashed using the SHA-256 algorithm. See instructions and double-check your setup."

I've been following the instructions specified here: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10172785?hl=en#zippy=%2Cenable-enhanced-conversions-in-google-tag-manager-and-create-custom-javascript-variable

The part regarding "hashed using the SHA-256" appears to be incorrect, since Google in another part of their documentation say that the data shouldn't be se sent hashed, unless you're using the Google API (which is not the case here).

The only value not available in the data layer on the conversion page is "street" so I've left that field out entirely. The other attributes should be present in the data layer.

**Which steps have I taken?**
Step 1 -  Selected "Include user-provided data from your website" in the existing Google Ads pixel/tag.
Step 2 - Configured the variable type "User-provided data" and selected "Code" as type
Step 3 - The data source has the below code:

```
function () {

return {

"email": {{data.email}} ,

"phone_number": {{Telephone}} ,

"address": {

"first_name": {{First Name}} ,

"last_name": {{Last name}} ,

"city": {{City}} ,

"postal_code": {{zipCode}} ,

"country": {{Country ID}}

}

}

}
```

Can anyone see if their perhaps is something in the code that's not correct or if their could be any other possible reason why the enhanced conversions aren't collecting data?

Thanks in advance!

I've looked in to using the CSS selector method, but the conversion page only has email data.
Also tried "Manual configuration", but this requires all values to be present, otherwise you can't save (e.g. if "Address" is missing, you can't save)

I've also made test purchases and from what I can see, the conversion tag is picking up the attributes for enhanced conversions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not collecting an address remove the field entirely.

from Google Support:

Note that if your site doesn't collect one of those fields, remove the field entirely rather than leaving it blank. For example, a website that only collects emails and phone numbers would create a custom javascript variable that looks like this:

```
function () {

return {

"email": yourEmailVariable ,

"phone_number": yourPhoneVariable

}

}
```